# $E(xy)<\infty$ proof

Tags: regression, econometrics, expected-value, inequality

I am reviewing the best linear projection properties proof in Hansen's book on econometrics. Specifically, the proof according to which $E(xy)<\infty$. For this, it is assumed that $E(y^2)<\infty$ and $E||x||^2<\infty$. The proof is as follows:
$$\|E(xy)\|<E\|xy\|<\sqrt(E\|x\|^2)\sqrt(Ey^2)<\infty$$
Where $ x $ is a vector of random variables (dimension $k$x$1$) and $ y $ a random variable. $\|x\|$ is the norm or euclidian length.
The first inequality is based on Expectation Inequeality and the first equality is based on the Cauchy-Schawarz Inequality. $$$$ Two questions; First, since $E (xy)$ is not explicitly in the inequality, from what part of it is its finiteness deduced? Second, all the members of the inequality are real numbers, however $E(xy)$ is a vector of dimension $k$x$1$, how then can this comparison be made?

Comment: If $xy$ is a $(k, 1)$-vector, what kind of objects are $x$ and $y$, and what type of product is being used?

Comment: What does "$E(xy)$ is finite" mean? I'd say: it has finite norm. What else?

Comment: $x$ is a vector of dimension $(k,1)$ and $y$ a scalar. Scalar-matrix product.

Comment: @Sergio I don't know exactly what it means, that's where my confusion can come from. I think that all the components of the vector must be finite, right?

Comment: If the components are not finite, then the norm is not finite; if the norm is finite, then the components are finite: $(\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q)$.